# Why is my nested IF not working in Smarty when using first and last properties?

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I'm trying to create a combination of names with a first and a last property. This works, but when i nest it into another if it goes broken.

Regular code:

```
{{foreach from=$xxx.aaaa item='aaaa_item' name=members}}    

        {{if $smarty.foreach.members.last}}
        &nbsp;&&nbsp;{{$aaaa.bbbb}}
        {{elseif $smarty.foreach.members.first}}
        {{$aaaa.bbbb}}
        {{else}}
        ,&nbsp;{{$aaaa.bbbb}}
        {{/if}}
     {{/foreach}}
```

Results

> name, name, name & name

Nested code:

```
{{foreach from=$xxx.aaaa item='aaaa_item' name=members}} 
    {{if $aaaa_item.cccc == "no"}}

        {{if $smarty.foreach.members.last}}
        &nbsp;&&nbsp;{{$aaaa.bbbb}}
        {{elseif $smarty.foreach.members.first}}
        {{$aaaa.bbbb}}
        {{else}}
        ,&nbsp;{{$aaaa.bbbb}}
        {{/if}}


    {{/if}}
{{/foreach}}
```

Results

> ,name, name, name

So it only give the result of the final 'else'

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution actually:

```
{{foreach from=$xxx.aaaa item=aaaa' name=members}}
    {{if $aaaa_item.cccc == "no"}}      
        {{if $smarty.foreach.members.first}}{{$aaaa.bbbb}}
        {{elseif $smarty.foreach.members.last}}&nbsp;&&nbsp;{{$aaaa.bbbb}}
        {{elseif $smarty.foreach.members}},&nbsp;{{$aaaa.bbbb}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
{{/foreach}}
```